# ViewChildren.changes.subscribe is triggered even when the changes didn't happen to ViewChildren

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-changedetection

I'm working on an angular app which has a parent and a list of children components. The parent uses two api calls:

- A: returns a boolean that show/remove the children from the DOM.
- B: show/remove a title in a div in the parent component.

I wanted to add a property to each child via ViewChildren decorator and ngAfterViewInit, so I put the following in it in the parent.

```
  @ViewChildren(ChildrenComponent) children: QueryList<ChildrenComponent>;


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.children.changes.subscribe((children) => {
       children.forEach((child) => {
           child = 'Property!!'; // this string is dynamic in my app.
       })
    });
  }
```

The subscription was triggered after API call A has returned. It's expected, since a new child is added to the QueryList. However, after API call B has returned, it also gets called.

Based on the documentation on ViewChildren decorator, it should only get called when a child is added, moved, removed from QueryList. However, API call B only touches a div outside of the children. Why did it triggers the subscription?

I have included a SandBox to illustrate this behavior: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-fll6r

ViewChildren documentation: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 0):

Your apiARes will be activated after 1 second. Within the period, there is no child loaded inside the parent. For demonstration purposes, you will get `undefined` when you check

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.children) //undefined
    // API call A
}
```

Once the API is called, the child is loaded which is a change detection in the child. You will get Query result

```
setTimeout(() => {
      this.apiARes = true;
      console.log(this.children) // Query result
    }, 1000);
```

`ngAfterViewInit()` is called after the view of child is initially rendered. This is why `@ViewChildren()` depends on it. We can't access child members before they are rendered.

Comment: Um... that's not my question. My question is why apiBRes, which hide/remove a div in the parent, would trigger the subscription callback. Thanks for the help!

Comment: As I mentioned above, apiBRes doesn't trigger your subscription. Your child is not loaded when `ngOnInit`. Once the child is rendered in `ngAfterViewInint`, its a change detection.

Comment: I understand that no children is loaded in ngOnInit. The child is loaded after ngAfterViewInit because the apiARes was set from the callback in setTimeout. This will change this.triggered for the first time. However, this.triggered was changed again after apiBRes was set. You are saying that the second change was due to apiARes too?